# Finding proportions based on data.frame subsets

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, apply

I have a set of counts from data with three dimensions:

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "C"), group = c("Tp", "Tp", "Tp", "Tp", "Fc", "Fc", "Fc", "Fc"), size = c(10,20,30,40,10,20,30,40), count = c(1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 10, 2, 3))

  type group size count
1    A    Tp   10     1
2    B    Tp   20     4
3    B    Tp   30     2
4    A    Tp   40     3
5    A    Fc   10     2
6    C    Fc   20    10
7    B    Fc   30     2
8    C    Fc   40     3
```

I would like to find the proportion that each count takes up but subset over both type and group dimensions. That is, for example, what is the farction of size 10's that are in group "Tp" and of type "A"?

I thought there might be a function that was like `aggregate` or something within the `plyr` package but would calculate data per row based on subsets but I can't seem to find it. My best effort is using apply:

```
df$prop <- apply(df, 1, function(x) as.numeric(x["count"])/sum(df[df$type==x["type"] & df$group==x["group"], "count"]))

  type group size count      prop
1    A    Tp   10     1 0.2500000
2    B    Tp   20     4 0.6666667
3    B    Tp   30     2 0.3333333
4    A    Tp   40     3 0.7500000
5    A    Fc   10     2 1.0000000
6    C    Fc   20    10 0.7692308
7    B    Fc   30     2 1.0000000
8    C    Fc   40     3 0.2307692
```

I just wondered if there is an easier way of doing this? If not I will write this up as a custom function.

Thanks.

Comment: Your definition of `df` is missing the size column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
transform(df, prop=count/ave(count, type, group, FUN=sum))
```

Comment: So the function I was missing was `ave`. I've never used `transform` either but it looks like it is just saving on a bit of typing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With plyr,

```
ddply(df, c("type","group"), mutate, prop = count/sum(count))

  type group size count      prop
1    A    Fc   10     2 1.0000000
2    A    Tp   10     1 0.2500000
3    A    Tp   40     3 0.7500000
4    B    Fc   30     2 1.0000000
5    B    Tp   20     4 0.6666667
6    B    Tp   30     2 0.3333333
7    C    Fc   20    10 0.7692308
8    C    Fc   40     3 0.2307692
```

Answer (score 0):

The much better scaling and imo more intuitive `data.table` way:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

dt[, prop := count/sum(count), by = list(type, group)]
```